# Experiences wanted: producing a jar artifact in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

Developing with IntelliJ 9.0.2 Community Edition, on the Mac.

This is a follow-up to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863579/intellij-including-jars-in-a-jar-artifact) about including jar files in an artifact, which has not received any replies.  I'm hoping that the reason is that somehow, in creating my artifact (or setting my project settings), I unwittingly did something which people don't tend to do, and which is causing my problem, and that by asking people here to share how they create jar artifacts and set up projects, I will discover what it is.

To recap: I have a Java project which depends on two library files.  I need to package up the entire thing, with the jars inlined (such that on doing `jar -tfv <filename>` I see ALL the classes listed, including the ones in the two libraries), into a single jar file.  I can make an artifact, I can add the library files to the Output Layout pane, but I CANNOT, no matter what I do, I cannot get the "Inline Artifact" item in the context menu to be selectable (i.e. non-grey) when I right-click on one or other library file.

The thing is, making a jar which contains library files as well as the project code is NOT an unusual situation in the Java world!  So I figure there are lots of IntelliJ folks out there who have done what I need to do.  And I would really like to hear from you folks.

What project settings do you use?  (be specific, please :-)

And exactly how do you set up your jar artifacts?  (again, as many specific details as possible, please :-)

Clearly, I'd be particularly interested to hear from folks with similar setups to mine (above) who are successfully doing what I need to do.

Grateful thanks in advance, folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much you can do from inside IntelliJ, but there are several ways to do it from outside by merging the JARs.

See here: [Selective jar packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888119/selective-jar-packaging/2888143)

Comment: Thanks yes I saw that post, I was hoping it was possible from within IntelliJ.  Apparently it will be in the next version...roll on! :-)