# Reference to a jar lib results in ClassNotFoundException with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, manifest, minecraft

I am compiling a plugin for minecraft which basically play a song on login.
Source code can be found [here](https://github.com/IQbrod/MC_Excilys).

A plugin already exists and provides a media player with a tutorial which I followed [MC_Jukebox](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/mcjukebox.16024/), source code is [here](https://github.com/oliverdunk/JukeboxAPI)

My code use this external jar to do the job :

```java
package com.iqbrod.excilysplugin;

import net.mcjukebox.plugin.bukkit.api.JukeboxAPI;
import net.mcjukebox.plugin.bukkit.api.ResourceType;
import net.mcjukebox.plugin.bukkit.api.models.Media;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class LoginListener implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) {
        Media media = new Media(ResourceType.MUSIC, "https://od.lk/s/MTFfMjQ2ODM2NTRf/music1.mp3");
        JukeboxAPI.play(event.getPlayer(), media);
    }
}
```

This code is correct and should play a music on a `PlayerJoinEvent`.
My problem comes from compilation to jar which contains:

```py
com/* #Source code
lib/* #external Jars (MC_Jukebox)
plugin.yml #required by Minecraft Server
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF #details below
```

Source code `com/*` is basic Java and correct compared to existing plugins/code. `Lib` contains my library jar. `plugin.yml` is correct and works without the references to lib classes. `MANIFEST.MF` is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: EntryPoint
Class-Path: lib/
```

**PROBLEM**
Even with a reference to `lib` in Class-Path of `MANIFEST` running server & client results in

```sh
[13:26:27] [Server thread/ERROR]: Could not pass event PlayerJoinEvent to ExcilysPlugin v1.0 org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/mcjukebox/plugin/bukkit/api/models/Media
(...)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.mcjukebox.plugin.bukkit.api.models.Media
```

How can I reference the jar contained in my jar under the folder `lib` ?

I'm using **Intellij** to code and compile.
I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863579/intellij-including-jars-in-a-jar-artifact) and also tried to use "Extract Folder".
Both results in a ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jars reference in MANIFEST points to local directory (`.minecraft/plugins/`) and not source code one.

**To solve this:** My external jars are in `.minecraft/plugins/lib` and not `.minecraft/plugins/myplugin/lib`.
Another solution is to point these jars in `MANIFEST.mf` as

> ClassPath: myplugin/lib

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to install the McJukebox plugin on your server, running your own custom plugin. I guess that otherwise, your plugin won't work. In general it should be enough to export the source/jar files containing the classes you need in you plugin. You can also [load jars through a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime).

Comment: Found a solution & understood through testing multiples possibilities, forgot to close the post :/ I don't want to install the plugin, only to access embeded classes using it as an API.